# plot function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a complete newbie to python (this is my first post) but I have some experience programming in R. I've been going through the [Crash Course in Python for Scientists](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/rpmuller/5920182?utm_campaign=Data%2BElixir&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Data_Elixir_36) tutorial.

I got as far as the matplotlib bit-I havent been able to go beyond this as the plot function is not recognized despite importing `matplotlib`. I'm using the idle in python 2.7.3 (I'm using a mac).

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> plot(range(20))
```

Here's the error message:
    # error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
plot(range(20))
NameError: name 'plot' is not defined
```

Can anyone help out at all? I know there are loads of other editors I could use but I prefer something similar to the `R console` where I can just type directly into the command line. I still haven't figured out a short cut for running a code directly from the idle editor-my `f5 key` is for something else and it doesn't run when I type it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plot` is a function of `matplotlib.pyplot`, so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(20))
```

**EDIT:**

To see the plot, you will normally need to call

```
plt.show()
```

to display the figure, or

```
plt.savefig('figname.png')
```

to save the figure to a file after calling `plt.plot()`.

As @JRichardSnape pointed out in the comments, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is now a widely used convention, and is often implied around this site. The [beginners guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/beginner.html) has some useful information on this.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. it gave me [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x1069611d0>] and then its trying to load the output which is taking ages. cheers.

Comment: you might need to call `plt.show()` after `plt.plot` to view the plot

Comment: Just a thought - don't want to steal your thunder by adding another answer - it's worth highlighting for a new user that you (usually) need to follow this with `plt.show()` to see the actual plot. It might also be worth highlighting that `as plt` is a widely used convention and often assumed and pointing to the [beginner's guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/beginner.html)

Comment: Oops - just noticed that a load of comments hadn't refreshed in my browser for some reason - sorry.

Comment: @JRichardSnape no worries, its all helpful info

Answer (score 3):

You have to import the `pyplot` module of `matplotlib` and call the
plot function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This `plt` is an alias for `matplotlib.pyplot`, so when
plotting your range of values, just use the defined alias:

```
plt.plot(range(20))
```

I usually need to show my plots to colleages, so I save them in a figure
instead of showing directly:

```
plt.savefig('output_image.png', dpi=300)
```

But if you need only a brief look in the output, just `show` your plot:

```
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

> I prefer something similar to the R console where I can just type
>   directly into the command line.

`matplotlib` is a plotting library, far from being the environment you seem to be seeking

If you want an environment similar to R, you probably will want to use `pylab` along with `matplotlib`

```
from pylab import *
plot(...)
show()
```

e.g. http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html

Also consider using `ipython` instead of the stock IDLE/Python prompt, highly recommended for data science, http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html#ipython-to-the-rescue

That gives a much better environment, notice the `%pylab` command to trigger that mode, or try `ipython --pylab` to launch it

If you're used to doing literate programming in R, I recommend learning IPython notebooks, http://ipython.org/notebook.html

Comment: but this isn't recommended any more: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related

Comment: That's the closest you can get to a numerical computing environment, not same thing as making sound programs

Comment: fair enough, I guess it just comes down to personal preference at some point

Comment: @John added a note on `ipython`, notebooks etc to bridge you from `R` to a Python centric data science environment